# Counter for words and emoji

Tags: python, string, pandas, counter, emoji

I have a dataframe with a column "clear_message", and I created a column that counts all the words in each row.

```
history['word_count'] = history.clear_message.apply(lambda x: Counter(x.split(' ')))
```

For example, if the rows message is: `Hello my name is Hello`
Then the counter in his row, will be `Counter({'Hello': 2, 'is': 1, 'my': 1, 'name': 1})`

**The problem**

I have emoji in my text, and I want also a counter for the emoji.

For example:

```
test = 'here sasdsa'
test_counter = Counter(test.split(' '))
```

The output is:

```
Counter({'sasdsa': 1, 'here': 1})
```

But I want:

```
Counter({'sasdsa': 1, '': 5, 'here':1})
```

Clearly the problem is that I'm using `split(' ')`.

**What I thought about:**

Adding a space before and after the emoji. like:

```
test = '     here sasdsa'
```

And then use the split, which will work.

1. Not sure this approach is the best.
2. Not sure how to do it. (I do know that if `i` is an emoji, then `if i in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI` will return true (the `emoji` package)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your idea of adding a space after each emoji is a good approach. You'll also need to strip white space in case there already was a space between an emoji and the next character, but that's simple enough. Something like:

```
def emoji_splitter(text):
    new_string = ""
    for char in text:
        if char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:
            new_string += " {} ".format(char)
        else:
            new_string += char
    return [v for v in map(lambda x: x.strip(), new_string.split(" ")) if v != ""]
```

Maybe you could improve this by using a sliding window to check for spaces after emojis and only add spaces where necessary, but that would assume there will only ever be one space, where as this solution should account for 0 to n spaces between emojis.

Comment: There were a few problems with this code, like counting `''` and no space before the first emoji. I added a few stuff, and posted it here as an answer. Tell me what you think. Thanks :)

Comment: Another issue is that it appears to split complex emoji, i.e. soemthing like `'‍‍'` becomes `['', '\u200d', '', '\u200d', '']`.

Answer (score 1):

there was some problems with @con-- answer, so I fixed it.

```
def emoji_splitter(text):
    new_string = ""
    text = text.lstrip()
    if text:
        new_string += text[0] + " "
    for char in ' '.join(text[1:].split()):
        new_string += char
        if char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:
            new_string = new_string + " " 
    return list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), new_string.split()))
```

example:

```
emoji_splitter(' a ads')
Out[7]: ['a', '', '', '', 'ads']
```

Comment: Good catch! I did miss the case about not having a space before the first emoji. However, I don't think your solution fully solves it either. For example if you try ```emoji_splitter('aa ads')``` your code should return ```['a', 'a', '', '', 'ads']``` since you insert a space between the first and second character, not the first emoji. I've edited my answer and I think I've accounted for all cases now, by surrounding all emojis in spaces, splitting on spaces and then removing any empty strings left in the list.

Comment: Seems to make the problems in the other answer worse, unable to handle complex emoji, unable to handle flag emoji.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd revisit this question, using a string with more complex emoji graphemes.

If we take a string `' a ads‍‍ bs'` the two older answers will return: `['a', '', '', '', 'ads', '', '\u200d', '', '\u200d', '', 'bs']` and `['a', '', '', '', 'ads', '\u200d', '\u200d', 'bs']`.

Both solutions handle simple emoji, but fail with more complex emoji graphemes.

Below I will use a number of Unicode regular expressions using the *regex* module, rather than the *re* module.

I've split the processing into three discrete functions, so it is easier to follow.

`split_emoji()` will split emoji substrings into individual graphemes. So  is split into three, ‍‍ remains as one item, as does .

`prep_string()` will add extra space around sequences of letters, then will split emoji graphemes, returning a string.

`count_elements()` will call prep_string, split the resultant string on one or more whitespace characters, then count the elements.

```py
import regex
from collections import Counter

def split_emoji(e):
    if regex.match(r'\p{Emoji}+', e):
        return ' '.join(regex.findall(r'\X', e))
    return e

def prep_string(text):
    text = regex.sub(r'(\p{L}+)', r" \1 ", text)
    items = [split_emoji(substr) for substr in text.split()]
    return " ".join(items)

def count_elements(text):
    return Counter(regex.split(r'\s+', prep_string(text)))

s = ' a ads‍‍ bs'
count_elements(s)
# Counter({'': 3, 'a': 1, 'ads': 1, '\u200d\u200d': 1, 'bs': 1, '': 1})
```

There are further refinements and edge cases that could be incorporated, like injecting spaces between punctuation and emoji, or stripping punctuation.